# Class attribute does not applay to textBoxFor

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the following code to change the text box width according to text
and currenlty its working OK for input type

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myclass').css('width', (($('.myclass').val().length)+1) * 6 + 'px'); 
});
```

This is the input type which is working

```
<input type="text" class="myclass"   disabled="disabled" style="margin-right: 5px;">
```

But for the following code its not working,any idea?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "myclass"})
```

Comment: What is the resulting HTML from your `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: Whats not working? If the width not being set correctly?

Comment: @RGraham-this is the html <input class="myclass valid"  name="service" type="text" value="catalog" style="width: 278px;">

Comment: @StephenMuecke-the width is not changing accordantly like in the input fields...

Comment: @Exception-not sure that I got you ?

Comment: just see here http://jsfiddle.net/kartikeya/269cw6L2/   its working

Comment: @Exception, try adding another textbox and you will see that its not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke..i know that but here he has posted only one textbox with myclass class and i m answering here as per question..and instead of 6 multiplier 7 multiplier is appropriate..

Comment: @Exception-Thanks but for text like following its not working value=catalog11111111AAAAAAAAA/BBBBBB/DDDD

Comment: try multiplier 7.5...

Answer (score -1):

you should have to use something like::

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Service, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "myclass"})
```

this is working.